# Deleting a range of rows from a table based on another table as input in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server. I need help to remove a range of rows from Table1 using input values and matching Ids from Table2.

Table1

| RowId | SetId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

Table2

| StartId | EndId | SetId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 8 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |

Result Table

| RowId | SetId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

So far this is the non-working code I have. I want to Delete RowId's from Table1 where they are greater than or equal to and less than or equal to the StartId and EndId of Table2 and having matching SetId's from Table1.

```
Delete From Table1
Where RowId >= 
(Select StartId From Table2 Where Table1.SetId = Table2.SetId) 
and RowId <= 
(Select EndId From Table2 Where Table1.SetId = Table2.SetId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `not exists`:

```
select * from table1 t1
where not exists (
select 1
from table2 t2
where t1.RowId between t2.StartId and t2.EndId
and t1.setid = t2.setid
)
```

and if you want to delete those rows:

```
delete from table1 t1
where exists (
select 1
from table2 t2
where t1.RowId between t2.StartId and t2.EndId
and t1.setid = t2.setid
)
```